# Remove all text but one word with VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a line of text that is an address: 1234 N. Main Street Atlanta 30000 Georgia

I want the only text remaining to be Georgia. What is the VBscript to do this? I am new to VBscripting but not to coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily the best way, but you could split it into an array on the space, and take the last element.

```
arrAddress = Split(szAddress, " ")
szState = arrAddress(UBound(arrAddress))
```

You could also use [`InStrRev`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2ekk41a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to locate the position of the last space, and use `Right(string, length)` to pull the state out.

Comment: UBound(a) is the last index (not the size/length) of a; so please remove the -1.